# Securesocial, Issues calling linkedin request after authentication

Tags: playframework-2.0, linkedin-api, securesocial

I'm trying to use securesocial to authenticate to Linkedin over OAuth1 and get list of connections of the connected user.

The authentication works fine, but calling any request after the user is connected, will return 401 response.
I'm maybe doing it wrong, but I don't see the potential issue.

Here is a simple method added to the Java Demo app provided within securesocial code:

```
@SecureSocial.SecuredAction ( authorization = WithProvider.class, params = {"linkedin"})
public static Result linkedinConnections(){
    Identity user = (Identity) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);        
    OAuth1Info oauthInfo = user.oAuth1Info().get();

    String url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(headline,first-name,last)?format=json";
    String consumerKey = SecureSocial.serviceInfoFor(user).key().key();
    String consumerSecret = SecureSocial.serviceInfoFor(user).key().secret();

    return async(
            WS.url(url)
            .sign(
                new OAuthCalculator(
                    new OAuth.ConsumerKey(consumerKey, consumerSecret), 
                    new OAuth.RequestToken(oauthInfo.token().toString(), oauthInfo.secret().toString())
                )
            )
            .get()
            .map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    return ok(response.getStatusText());
                }
            })
        );
}
```

Any idea will help

Regards,
Nabil

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to use SecureSocial with LinkedIn but given that

- The authentication with SecureSocial works
- You would like to list the connections of a LinkedIn user
- Your own method always gets a 401 error (Unauthorized)

It seems obvious that you are mixing two different access levels. The authentication performed by SecureSocial only requires basic info like name or mail address, from LinkedIn. Then with the same authentication token, you would like to access advanced infos of the LinkedIn user (its connections). This is of course denied (Unauthorized) by LinkedIn because the user only gave you the permission to access his basic profile, not his contacts/connections.

If you wish to gain more permissions in order to list the connections of a user, I think you have to add the scope info to the OAuth authentication request sent by SecureSocial. This probably implies that you will have to edit the source file of the module to add the scope info.

See https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication for LinkedIn scope and permissions. See https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/LinkedInProvider.scala for the LinkedIn SecureSocial code.

Hope this helps.